# View added from XML file is not shown in its parent view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-view

In my *Player* activity I am trying to add a view from a different XML by calling `addView`:

```
    view = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.player_ConstraintLayout);
    notifierView = LayoutInflater.from(view.getRootView().getContext())
                                 .inflate(R.layout.notifier, null);
    view.addView(notifierView);
    // view.invalidate();
```

The *Player* activity comes with this associated XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/player_ConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.Player">

    ...

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the one I want to add is notifier.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:translationZ="9dp"
    android:elevation="9dp">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have debugged the app and by inspecting variable `view` I can confirm that the `notifierView` has been added and is in the children list of the `view`. However the `notifierView` is not shown, even I have expected it to be of full screen size and red. When I inspected `notifierView` in debugger, it showed its `mTop`, `mBottom`, `mLeft`, and `mRight` variables being all `0`. I assuming it means that the

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

have been ignored? Or is there some other reason why I don't see this `notifierView` at all?

---

EDIT/UPDATE:

Let me show you more of the code, as the previous above is a little simplified one.

In *Player* activity I have:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

    notifier = new Notifier((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.player_ConstraintLayout));

    ...

}
```

and in *Notifier.java* I have

```
Notifier(ViewGroup view) {    
    handler = new android.os.Handler();    
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(view.getRootView().getContext());
    notifierView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notifier, view, false);    
}
```

Comment: I just tried your code, even with `match_parent`, it works. Please show the full code of `activity_player`. Btw, you can call `LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.notifier, view, true)` and it will also add it to the `ViewGroup`

Comment: @lelloman - My code is a huge project, it would be a lot of pages :)

Comment: ok so, why are you instantiating a `Handler` in `Notifier`? are you really adding `Notifier` in `onCreate`?

Comment: @lelloman - Yes, my `Notifier` is a replacement of `Toast` and I need `Handler` for `handler.postDelayed(runnable, duration);` to cancel the notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author)*.

<kbd>Invalidate Caches / Restart</kbd> helped. Android Studio sometime gets things wrong.

Answer (score 3):

`ConstraintLayout` doesn't actually support `match_parent` for its children. You have to use this for "match parent" width:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

And this for "match parent" height:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Additionally, your `LayoutInflater.inflate()` call should be changed. When you pass `null` as the second argument, you don't give the system enough information to understand how to parse `layout_` attributes on the inflated view; you should pass a real parent (in this case, `view`). However, if you change `null` to `view`, the return value of the `inflate()` call will change, so you have to add an additional param (`attachToRoot`) to make sure the rest of the semantics don't change.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(view.getRootView().getContext());
notifierView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notifier, view, false);
```

Comment: First, I believe `ConstraintLayout` does support `match_parent` for its children. But I went ahead and used your recommendations and your code. Unfortunately there is no difference. It is not shown and the `mLeft`, `mTop`, `mRight` and `mButtom` are still `0`.

Comment: @Ωmega the documentation seems to agree with me. https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html search for "Set size as a ratio" and look just above that. "Note: You cannot use match_parent for any view in a ConstraintLayout. Instead use "match constraints" (0dp)."

Comment: @Ωmega is it possible you've omitted relevant code from your question? In my testing with a very basic layout, what I posted works fine, but also just using default layout params gives me match/match dimensions.

Comment: When you build a simple app with `ConstraintLayout` inside of its parent (transparent) `ConstraintLayout` and set `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to both of them, with some background color on children layout, you will see it does work.

Comment: There has to be something else what causes the problem. I have coded `android:layout_width="50dp"` and `android:layout_height="50dp` to see if I will get something, but unfortunately there is nothing shown and all coordinates are still `0`.

Comment: @Ωmega have you changed the inflate() call as well? If you're still using `null` as the root, it doesn't matter what you set for width/height.

Comment: Yes, I did. I have updated my question - see above. Thanks!

Comment: **Invalidate Caches / Restart** helped. Both codes are fine, but Android Studio sometimes gets it wrong. Thanks for your help and time spent on this question.